# How can I get the second response from service with callback method?

Tags: webos, enyo

I am currently sending following luna-send command to detect sms database change:

```
luna-send -n 2 -a my_app luna://com.palm.db/find '{"query":{"from":"com.palm.smsmessage:1",
"where":[{"prop":"folder","op":"=","val":"inbox}]},"watch":true
```

The first response returns the existing database data and the second one is delivered when the database is changed.

This works fine, but when I convert this to code for my enyo app, my callback method is not called for the second response. I am using enyo.bind(this, my_callbackmethod). It seems like my callback method is only called once.

Is there any way to get the second response using callback method?

Comment: Are you putting my_callbackmethod in quotes in that call?

Comment: @Pre101 nope. I am putting it like this.my_callbackmethod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, not sure I've ever used **watch**.  What if you use **subscribe: true**?

Comment: I am using watch:true and subscribe:true at the same time, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I am currently using enyo2.0 so that I cannot call PalmService. Thus, I am using PalmServiceBridge directly and passing parameters. Can this cause subscribe function not working? Enyo 1.0 uses makeRequestProps to handle subscribe param saying including subscribe in params directly is not supported. I don't know how to apply this to my custom ServiceRequest which is using PalmServiceBridge directly.

Comment: Hmmm, that is a pickle.  The best I can come up with right now is to check to see how Cordova does it.  I know their library sets up a subscribe to connection manager.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-webos